# Get data between two timestamps AND the data just before and just after

Tags: cassandra, intervals, cql

Let's say I have a table containing purchases (with clientId as partitionKey, and timestamp for clustering key).

**Problem :**

I'm wondering what would be the best way to get all the purchases of one client between *dateA* and *dateB* and also the first purchase before *dateA* and the first purchage after *dateB*.

**What I've done so far :**

Actually I make 3 requests to Cassandra:

1) before dateA max 1

2) between dateA and dateB

3) after dateB max 1

Is it possible to improve this ? (in one request ?)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Probably not in one request without degrading performance. Cassandra is fast and calls to the DB are cheap - making 3 calls over one probably isn't a problem.

Comment: You said 'get all the purchases'. But all the purchases of one clientId or for all clientId. Can you provide one exemple. Maybe you could look on secondary indexes but it can slow down your performences.